# SSRS Charts - Horizontally instead of Vertically

Tags: charts, ssrs-2012

We have over 10 charts in the report. We grouped the charts and displayed the results correctly.  However, we have a big white space to the right side because the charts were stacked on top of each other.

Is there anyway, we can put the charts horizontally?  We would like the result to be like this below. So, the white spaces on the right could be eliminated..

[image: Current and Proposed]

Comment: What does you current report layout look like, can you edit and show a sceenshot of that? Are the chart inside a tablix, maybe using subreports) or just manually placed on the report? The answer to these questions will make a big difference to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. If you mouse over the edge of the report in report builder, you'll notice the mouse turns to a left-right toggle. Click and drag right to expand the width of your report. You can now move your chart into that empty space.